# sending messages from a datasource object to a view objective c

Tags: ios, uiview, datasource, nsmanagedobject

I have a custom uiview subclass that gets the data it needs to display from a datasource which is a subclass of nsmanagedobject. Is there any way that the nsmanagedobject subclass can hold a pointer to the view? I would like to do this so that the view controller can get some information about the frame size of the uiview by asking the datasource how much space its view takes up.

Comment: Your view controller should be the middle man.  It should ask datasource how much data, get the data, etc. and properly allocates/formats/prepares the UIView accordingly.  And then display the UIView.  After all that is the reason why it is a view controller!

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for. What I was doing before was using sizeWithFont to set the subview frames to the right size to display text and numbers, and then later if I needed that information I would just hold a pointer to the view so I could just use object.view.frame.width to access the width. but it makes sense to just go back and recalculate those properties in the controller each time instead of holding a pointer to that view. I will write a method that takes the object as an argument and returns a CGRect that will display excactly that much data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The major flaw in the design you are describing is that you have a UIView communicating **directly** with a data object. This goes against the basics of [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and it's very likely you can achieve whatever it is you need by introducing a controller between these two elements. Please elaborate a little more about the frame size you're trying to calculate for a more detailed answer.